# Unable to load GLTF file in ASP.NET View implementing A-FRAME

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, aframe, gltf

One of the views (.cshtml file) of my ASP.NET MVC application is using A-Frame. I am trying to load a 3-D model using GLTF file inside the `<a-scene>` tag.

```
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets timeout="5000">
            <a-asset-item id="tree" src="~/Assets/scene.gltf">
        </a-assets>
        <a-gltf-model src="#tree"></a-gltf-model>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

I have already tested the `src` path in the same page by putting a `.png` file and loading it in `<img/>`, it works. The problem is just with the `.gltf` file.

What is possibly wrong with the `.gltf` file in particular?

Comment: Have you tried dropping the glTF file into the [Khronos glTF Validator](http://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/)?  If the problems there aren't obvious, can you share the glTF or a reduced glTF with us?

Comment: Do you see the model fetched on the browser network panel?

Comment: @emackey i have validated it. It loads fine when we use it in a node application.

Comment: Check for errors in the web console (F12), see if there are any messages related to not loading the glTF file.

Answer (score 0):

The URL doesn't seem like a valid URL. It seems like a Unix path. Host the GLTF somewhere the website can reach it (like the same directory) and fix the path. `src="scene.gltf"`.

Comment: It works fine by hosting the file separately and then using it in the page. Thanks!